# What is a ballpark daily rate for a senior freelance front-end developer in NY?

Tags: contracts, price, usa, working-from-home

I live in London, and prices vary from £300 up to £500+. Can anybody tell me what are the rates in New York?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this including taxes? Is this for individuals (freelancers) or what companies charge when renting their employee? As I also heard about 300GBP per day.

Comment: why this has been downvoted? it's a legitimate question.

Comment: I don't think we should be allowing questions about what rates are in specific places. That could lead to a ton of questions that are not applicable a very short span of time later, and that wouldn't be too good.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I don't live in New York.

From what I read on forums and around here, hourly rate for individual freelancers starts from $50 per hour (junior) up to $100 or $120 per hour for experienced person. I heard people often saying "I gave him discount to $80 per hour" so I'd say the hourly price is between $80 and $100.

New York has the same living costs as London so I think you can also convert London hourly price to USD.

Another solution is to find the latest results on living costs in New York and London, compare them and then using math calculate what should New York fee be compared to London's fee.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I want to find out. I roughly know what the costs of living in NY might be, but I don't know how much could I actually make there. And to answer your previous question, you need to pay tax on top of the prices I quoted. Approx. 20-40%, depending on your circumstances. So assuming you're making £300 per day, you're left with about £180.

Comment: Also, you're confusing hourly rate with daily rate. Hourly rate is most likely to be charged when you freelance directly, then you manage your own clients and you can bill them whatever you want. I am talking about freelancing through an agent - which is a completely different story. There are no 'hourly rates', only daily.

Comment: @goodpixels, In the US, when going through an agency, there aren't typically daily rates either, just a salary for the length of the contract. Here it is usually hourly, fixed price, or salaried if going through an agency.